# ImportError: No module named mbtiapp.models

Tags: windows, django

I have installed python2.7 and django 1.3.1 on my XP pc. I am also running a MySQL database. Inspired by the first django app tutorial, I have created a project 'mysite' with an application 'mbtiapp'. The directory structure is as follows (I have omitted almost everything):

```
mysite  
mysite\mbtiapp  
mysite\mbtiapp\models.py  
mysite\mbtiapp\testMySQL.py
```

As you can see, there is a little python script 'testMySQL.py'. This is a little program that inserts a row in a database in the MySQL engine:

### testMySQL.py

```
from mbtiapp.models import InterestRate

i = InterestRate()
i.maturity_number = 2
i.maturity_unit = 'Y'
i.currency = 'USD'
i.rate = 2.8
i.save()
```

---

A few potentially relevant settings:

- The Windows environment variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings`
- Windows path: `C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;c:\jmbat;c:\MinGW\bin;c:\python27;c:Django-1.3.1;c:Django-1.3.1\django\bin`
- Python Path(sys.path): `'C:\\jmv_docs\\Dropbox\\python-programming\\projects\\django\\mysite', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\python27.zip', 'c:\\python27\\DLLs', 'c:\\python27\\lib', 'c:\\python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'c:\\python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'c:\\python27', 'c:\\python27\\lib\\site-packages', 'c:\\python27\\lib\\site-packages\\wx-2.8-msw-unicode'`

---

### QUESTION

If I run testMySQL.py from the mbtiapp (as depcted above) I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "mbtiapp\testMySQL.py", line 1, in <module>  
    from mbtiapp.models import InterestRate  
ImportError: No module named mbtiapp.models
```

However, when I place testMySQL.py one directory above (so directly in the 'mysite' directory) everyhting works fine and a row is inserted in the approproate table. The point is that I want to place my code in the app-directories (in this case 'mbtiapp') since this is where it belongs, not in the general project directory.

I am aware that quite a lot of similar looking questions can be found, but neither on the web, nor on the django site I have found a decent answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with importing. You can quickly fix it by changing import statement. Replace `mbtiapp.models` with `models` and it will work.

Comment: I am afraid is does not, when I do that, this is what I get:

Comment: It does not I am afraid. I then get: ImportError: Could not import settings 'settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named settings. I have also tried to change the sys.path by sys.path.append('C:\jmv_docs\Dropbox\python-programming\projects\Django\mysite') and this does not help either.

Comment: @Django: I do not see where do you import `settings` in your code. Do you run it on WSGI?